# I need to get the last 7 days in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with registration dates and I need to check who made a registration during the last 7 days. The table I use has the following shape:

```
create table GUEST(
    gNo          int, 
    gAT          varchar2(7)   unique, 
    gLastName    varchar2(40), 
    gFirstName   varchar(30), 
    gRegDate     date, 
    primary key(gNo)
);

insert into GUEST values
(150, 'A123987', 'NIKOLAOU', 'GEWRGIOS', TO_DATE('02/07/2022','DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

I've already tried this:

```
select gregdate 
from guest 
where gregdate <= sysdate - 7;
```

though it seems like it substracts 7 from month instead of day.

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: You `gregdate <= sysdate -7` implies that you want rows with gregdate earlier than sysdate-7, not  since. change the direction.

Comment: can you provide more samples data, the current output and the expected output? @PhoenixDoom

Comment: @lemon yes of course! So basically the output right now is this: ```02-JUL-22 |
22-SEP-22 |
15-OCT-22``` while what I need is something like ```05-JUN-22``` since its within the last 7 days

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=04a486fd7dcfbd7bc286196d0bda636e do you get the same results I'm getting here? @PhoenixDoom

Comment: yes i do get the same results (also edited the comment the expected output was wrong) @lemon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should get the days you need:

```
SELECT gregdate 
FROM guest 
WHERE gregdate > sysdate - 7 
  AND gregdate <= sysdate
```

The conditions will enclose the `gregdate` field in range `(sysdate - 7, sysdate]`, where the former boundary is not included while the latter one is.

Answer (score 0):

The condition here is wrong. It should be `sysdate - gregdate <=7` or `gregdate > sysdate -7`.

For clarity, The `7` is subtracted from the day (not from months).

You should also add check whether the `gregdate` is greater than the current date.

Comment: Tried both ways and im getting same results:
```02-JUL-22 |
22-SEP-22 |
15-OCT-22```

Comment: You are getting `02-JUL-22` because the gregdate is not more than 7 days ago. As the last line explains, you should also check whether the gregdate is the date of future or past. (if the constraints are properly implemented then the table does not have gregdate of the future).